# Webmasters.Searchanalytics.Query rowLimit works strange

Tags: google-search-console

I constructed query this way:

```
...

val request = new SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest()
  request.setStartDate(from)
  request.setEndDate(to)
  request.setDimensions(List("query", "page").asJava)
  request.setRowLimit(5000)
  request.setStartRow(0)

webmasters.searchanalytics().query(site, request)
```

result have 3343 rows

I tried to make paging - and for test reasons setup rowLimit at 1000
and i suggest to get 1000 then another 1000, and another 1000 and, finaly, 343 rows

from here https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/how-tos/search_analytics

> If your query has more than 5,000 rows of data, you can request data in batches of 5,000 rows at a time by sending multiple queries and incrementing the startRow value each time. Count the number of retrieved rows; if you get less than the number of rows requested, you have retrieved all the data. If your request ends exactly on the data boundary (for example, there are 5,000 rows and you requested startRow=0 and rowLimit=5000), on your next call you will get an empty response.

but i got only 559 rows !

when i set rowLimit at 100 - i got 51 rows!!!

What i doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same behavior, that looks like data sampling.

You can get more results (and then more accurate metrics) by fetching data day-by-day through multiple queries, instead of only one query ranging between two dates.

Hope, it helps!